# Apache poi MS word how to insert page number

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi

I am using APACHE POI to create word doc containing various tables.

I read up on the libraries but am still unsure of how to insert the page number at the bottom of every page in my document

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28822950/4553646) to your question

```
// create footer
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = doc.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
CTP ctpFooter = CTP.Factory.newInstance();

XWPFParagraph[] parsFooter;

// add style (s.th.)
CTPPr ctppr = ctpFooter.addNewPPr();
CTString pst = ctppr.addNewPStyle();
pst.setVal("style21");
CTJc ctjc = ctppr.addNewJc();
ctjc.setVal(STJc.RIGHT);
ctppr.addNewRPr();

// add everything from the footerXXX.xml you need
CTR ctr = ctpFooter.addNewR();
ctr.addNewRPr();
CTFldChar fch = ctr.addNewFldChar();
fch.setFldCharType(STFldCharType.BEGIN);

ctr = ctpFooter.addNewR();
ctr.addNewInstrText().setStringValue(" PAGE ");

ctpFooter.addNewR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.SEPARATE);

ctpFooter.addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("1");

ctpFooter.addNewR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.END);

XWPFParagraph footerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctpFooter, doc);

parsFooter = new XWPFParagraph[1];

parsFooter[0] = footerParagraph;

policy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsFooter);
```