# Apache POI how to add a page number

Tags: apache-poi

Just started to use POI 3.10 to create a Word document (XWPF).
Most of the things are straight forward, but I don't understand how to add page numbers.
I added the footer, but the text in the footer is the same on every page

Comment: How are you adding the page number to the footer currently? Can you show us the code you've tried?

Comment: I too require  - adding page numbers to footer... Could any one suggest on this...

Answer (score 8):

I created a page number in the footer on the right in LibreOffice and investigated the XML file (MS Word-Std-Objects are not supported in POI which is used there for page numbers).

This will enable to create more complex footers...

to set the number to other positions set another value for ctjc instead of STJc.RIGHT...

The result is the following:

```java
// create footer
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = doc.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
CTP ctpFooter = CTP.Factory.newInstance();

XWPFParagraph[] parsFooter;

// add style (s.th.)
CTPPr ctppr = ctpFooter.addNewPPr();
CTString pst = ctppr.addNewPStyle();
pst.setVal("style21");
CTJc ctjc = ctppr.addNewJc();
ctjc.setVal(STJc.RIGHT);
ctppr.addNewRPr();

// Add in word "Page "   
CTR ctr = ctpFooter.addNewR();
CTText t = ctr.addNewT();
t.setStringValue("Page ");
t.setSpace(Space.PRESERVE);

// add everything from the footerXXX.xml you need
ctr = ctpFooter.addNewR();
ctr.addNewRPr();
CTFldChar fch = ctr.addNewFldChar();
fch.setFldCharType(STFldCharType.BEGIN);

ctr = ctpFooter.addNewR();
ctr.addNewInstrText().setStringValue(" PAGE ");

ctpFooter.addNewR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.SEPARATE);

ctpFooter.addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("1");

ctpFooter.addNewR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.END);

XWPFParagraph footerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctpFooter, doc);

parsFooter = new XWPFParagraph[1];

parsFooter[0] = footerParagraph;

policy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsFooter);
```

Comment: I used this and got the page number to display! But I can not get the word PAGE to display as well. Can you hep? @Sempfer

Comment: Edited answer to add the word `PAGE`

Comment: You just saved me! thank you!...I am working on JDK 6 - poi  3.15

Comment: The solution worked for me, but doc.getHeaderFooterPolicy() was returning a null pointer, I had to change it to this:

CTSectPr sectPr = doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(doc, sectPr);

Answer (score 3):

org.apache.poi:poi:3.17, org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17, org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.3

```java
CTP ctp = CTP.Factory.newInstance();

CTText txt = ctp.addNewR().addNewT();
txt.setStringValue("Page ");
txt.setSpace(SpaceAttribute.Space.PRESERVE);

CTR run = ctp.addNewR();
run.addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.BEGIN);
run.addNewInstrText().setStringValue(" PAGE ");
run.addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.END);

txt = ctp.addNewR().addNewT();
txt.setStringValue(" of ");
txt.setSpace(SpaceAttribute.Space.PRESERVE);

run = ctp.addNewR();
run.addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.BEGIN);
run.addNewInstrText().setStringValue(" NUMPAGES ");
run.addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.END);

XWPFParagraph par = new XWPFParagraph(ctp, document);
par.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
if (policy == null)
  policy = document.createHeaderFooterPolicy();
policy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, new XWPFParagraph[] { par });
```

And you got `Page 1 of 9` in footer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CTP ctp = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
//this add page number incremental
ctp.addNewR().addNewPgNum();

XWPFParagraph codePara = new XWPFParagraph(ctp, document);
XWPFParagraph[] paragraphs = new XWPFParagraph[1];
paragraphs[0] = codePara;
//position of number
codePara.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();

try {
    XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document, sectPr);
    headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(STHdrFtr.DEFAULT, paragraphs);
} catch (IOException | XmlException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(STHdrFtr.DEFAULT, paragraphs); this line can be:                                                                                                                  headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(STHdrFtr.DEFAULT, paragraphs);

Comment: From the spec `Note: The pgNum Block is a legacy construct used for compatibility with older word processors, and should not be produced unless it was consumed while reading a document`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
XWPFParagraph p1 = doc.createParagraph();
XWPFRun r1 = p1.createRun();
r1.setText("Page ");
r1.getCTR().addNewPgNum();
r1.setText(" of 9");
p1.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
```