# Add a page number in header in .docx using apache poi

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, page-numbering

I have a text header in my .docx document which is aligned to the left hand side.
I want to add page number as "Page 1", "Page 2" and so on on the right hand side of the header.I am using Apache POI for the same, is there any possible way to do the same.I am using the below piece of code to add left aligned header -

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();         
CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document, sectPr);   
//write header content
CTP ctpHeader = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
CTR ctrHeader = ctpHeader.addNewR();
CTText ctHeader = ctrHeader.addNewT();
String headerText = "This is a header";
ctHeader.setStringValue(headerText);    
XWPFParagraph headerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctpHeader, document);
XWPFParagraph[] parsHeader = new XWPFParagraph[1];
parsHeader[0] = headerParagraph;
policy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsHeader);`
```

Please help me with any pointers on this issue.

Comment: If you create a document in Word with the numbered header, and read it back in POI, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. I am now able to add right aligned page number in the header.

I have used the below link as reference for the same -
[Apache POI how to add a page number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410967/apache-poi-how-to-add-a-page-number?rq=1)

The below code works fine for me now -

```
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

        CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
        XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document, sectPr);

        //write header content
        CTP ctpHeader = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
        CTR ctrHeader = ctpHeader.addNewR();
        CTText ctHeader = ctrHeader.addNewT();
        String headerText = "FISHER SCIENTIFIC COMPANY L.L.C. DISTRIBUTION AGREEMENT";
        ctHeader.setStringValue(headerText);    

        //write page number header
        CTP ctpHeaderPage = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
        CTPPr ctppr = ctpHeaderPage.addNewPPr();
        CTString pst = ctppr.addNewPStyle();
        pst.setVal("style21");
        CTJc ctjc = ctppr.addNewJc();
        ctjc.setVal(STJc.RIGHT);
        ctppr.addNewRPr();
        CTR ctr = ctpHeaderPage.addNewR();
        ctr.addNewRPr();
        CTFldChar fch = ctr.addNewFldChar();
        fch.setFldCharType(STFldCharType.BEGIN);

        ctr = ctpHeaderPage.addNewR();
        ctr.addNewInstrText().setStringValue(" PAGE ");

        ctpHeaderPage.addNewR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.SEPARATE);

        ctpHeaderPage.addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("1");

        ctpHeaderPage.addNewR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.END);

        XWPFParagraph headerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctpHeader, document);
        XWPFParagraph headerParagraphPage = new XWPFParagraph(ctpHeader, document);
        XWPFParagraph[] parsHeader = new XWPFParagraph[2];
        parsHeader[0] = headerParagraph;
        parsHeader[1] = headerParagraphPage;
        policy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsHeader);
```